# Classifying functions with certain properties

Tags: real-analysis

Another question that appeared on a qualifying exam that I'm trying to figure out:

Classify all functions $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ which satisfy:

1. f is Riemann Integrable on any bounded subinterval of $[0,\infty)$
2. $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$
3. $(f(x))^2 = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$

There is a hint telling to show first that any such f must be differentiable, and what I could see doing was writing that we'd like to show

$f'(x)=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \displaystyle \frac{\left(\int_{0}^{x+h}f(t)dt\right)^{1/2}-\left( \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt\right)^{1/2}}{h}$

Thanks for any ideas!

EDIT: So I've done a bit of it, but it's hard to tell if I've gotten all of the classifications...how do I know when to stop? :p

Comment: Applying chain rule might be a good start?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to argue about differentiability: The fundamental theorem of calculus implies immediately that $f(x)^2$ is differentiable, and that its derivative at $x$ is $f(x)$. Since $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, it follows that $f(x)=\sqrt {f(x)^2}$, and thus, $f$ is differentiable for all $x>0$, and its derivative is $\frac{f(x)}{2f(x)}=\frac{1}{2}$. I hope this helps you with going further.

Comment: wouldn't we need to show f s continuous on any $[0,x]$ before applying FTC?
EDIT: appearently 2nd FTC doesn't require continuity, cool!

Comment: well, you do need to argue something. Notice for instance that Riemann integrability implies continuity almost everywhere. I just tried to give some hints, there is more work to be done.